# Filter a list of dicts based on id

Tags: python, django

I have a List of dicts in python  like

```
[{u'id': 19, u'name': u'SYWSUB'},
 {u'id': 20, u'name': u'SYWSU'},
 {u'id': 40, u'name': u'Others'},
 {u'id': 41, u'name': u'rohit'},
 {u'id': 42, u'name': u'ssc'}]
```

I wanted to get all the items except the one who have id 42

Mean my output should be like

```
[{u'id': 19, u'name': u'SYWSUB'},
 {u'id': 20, u'name': u'SYWSU'},
 {u'id': 40, u'name': u'Others'},
 {u'id': 41, u'name': u'rohit'}]
```

I tried

```
other_category = [
    cat for cat in categories if cat['id'] !=  current_course_category ]
```

WHere current_course_category  value is 42

But this one is returning the whole list

```
[{u'id': 19, u'name': u'SYWSUB'},
 {u'id': 20, u'name': u'SYWSU'},
 {u'id': 40, u'name': u'Others'},
 {u'id': 41, u'name': u'rohit'},
 {u'id': 42, u'name': u'ssc'}]
```

Please tell me what might I am doing wrong ?>

Comment: Most likely your `current_course_category` is not an integer; I suspect it is probably a string instead.

Comment: What is `current_course_category`? and what is the type of it?

Comment: Value is 42 for that check updated

Comment: Either your `id` values are not integers, or `current_course_category` is not an integer. *Printing* either will not show the difference, use `repr()` when printing to show you more information about the *type*.

Comment: Is `current_course_category` an integer? If so, change to `str(current_course_category)`

Comment: Its my mistake because SOrry bothering I was passing current_course_category   without mentions integer

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be

```
categories = [{u'id': 19, u'name': u'SYWSUB'},
 {u'id': 20, u'name': u'SYWSU'},
 {u'id': 40, u'name': u'Others'},
 {u'id': 41, u'name': u'rohit'},
 {u'id': 42, u'name': u'ssc'}]

current_course_category = 42
print [cat for cat in categories if cat['id'] != current_course_category]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[ {key: value} for key, value in your_dict.items() if key != 42 ]

This should do it